# Mailto doesn't work on my html

Tags: html

I'm working on my portfolio and i've added an email with mailto like this

```
<a id="contact-email" href="mailto:example@gmail.com"><h3>Email: example@gmail.com</h3></a>
```

It works if i paste it inside www.w3schools.com "try it yourself" but when i'm trying to test it on my webpage it doesn't work

What can cause this problem?

Comment: can you show us your page?

Comment: Never say "it doesn't work" because that's ambiguous. Tell us what actually happens, or doesn't happen. By the way your HTML is invalid: your elements are the wrong way around: `<h3>` cannot exist inside an `<a>` element. It should be `<h3><a>email me</a></h3>`.

Comment: Yet another reason to not trust [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The `a` tag should be inside the `h3` like this:

```
<h3><a id="contact-email" href="mailto:example@gmail.com">Email : example@gamil.com</a></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the problem, apperently it doesn't work when working locally, when i've uploaded it on my website it worked correctly